# How use Transaction within an ASMX Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, transactions, asmx

i begin use Transaction in Web Service. i use C# and begin insert with Transaction.
But i don't insert to database.

**Code WebService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

[WebService(Namespace = "example.org")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm1, comm2, comm3;
    SqlTransaction trans;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter1, adapter2;
    DataSet ds1, ds2;
    string constring = "Database=transaction;server=localhost;user=sa;password=toon2255";

    [WebMethod(Description = "Transaction")]
    public string transaction(int userid, int amount)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
        conn.Open();
        comm2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO moneytrans VALUES('" + userid + "','" + amount + "')");
        trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
        comm2.Transaction = trans;
        try
        {
            comm2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trans.Commit();
            return "Transaction Complted. ";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            return "Transaction Failed..";
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Code Default.aspx.cx (Website)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

protected void btnok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WSLogin.WebService obj = new WSLogin.WebService();
        lblmsg.Text = obj.transaction(Convert.ToInt32(txtuserid.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtamount.Text));
    }
```

> But Result now "Transaction Failed.."
>
> i want Result "Transaction Compelted" and insert to database complete.

Comment: Where is the full exception info? I think you haven't trouble with transaction but with SQL query.

Comment: Log your exception , currently you are ignoring the caught exception. That will tell you what went wrong with your query.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you're ignoring exceptions. Don't *ever* ignore exceptions. They will usually tell you what's wrong with your code.

Your code has several other problems, as I'll explain with the following corrected code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "example.org")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    // 1
    const string constring = "Database=transaction;server=localhost;user=sa;password=toon2255";

    [WebMethod(Description = "Transaction")]
    public string transaction(int userid, int amount)
    {
        // 2
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            // 3
            using (SqlCommand comm2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO moneytrans VALUES(@userid,@amount)"))
            {
                comm2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid);
                comm2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", amount);

                // 4
                using (SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    comm2.Transaction = trans;
                    try
                    {
                        comm2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        trans.Commit();
                        return "Transaction Completed. ";
                    }
                    // 5
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        trans.Rollback();
                        // 6
                        return string.Format("Transaction Failed: {0}", ex);
                    }
                    // 7
                    //finally Not needed because of using block
                    //{
                    //    conn.Close();
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. It is usually best to declare variables near their point of use. As none of these variables were used except in the web method, I moved them all inside. I left the string constant outside.
2. The `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlTransaction` all need to be in `using` blocks, to make certain that any resources they use will be cleaned up with the block is finished, whether or not an exception is thrown. This is true for classes which implement the `IDisposable` interface, when you create them, use them, and finish using them all in the same span of code.
3. Another using block, but more importantly, I have used parameters as a best practice. You should not build SQL queries by string concatenation, as it allows your callers (or your users) to dictate the text of the query you will be executing. This prevents "SQL Injection Attacks".
4. Another `using` block. The `SqlTransaction` is created by the `BeginTransaction` method.
5. This is the worst problem with your code. Don't *ever* ignore exceptions. At the very least, be certain to log the exceptions somewhere where you can read them later.
6. For this example, I followed your practice of returning a string, but I added the full exception to the end of the string. Not pretty, but all the information will be there.
7. Because `conn` is in a `using` block, the explicit `finally` is not required. A `using` block is equivalent to a `try/catch/finally`.